# I want to output 1 3 4 5 7 9 but I hardly stuck here

Tags: c, function, recursion, parameters, parameter-passing

I have tried for two hours and cannot find the answer. 
If someone can help I will be very thankful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void somefunction(const int[], int);

int main() {
  int a[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
  somefunction(a, 5);
  return 0;
}

void somefunction(const int b[], int c) {
  if (c > 0) {
    somefunction(b[], c - 1);
    printf("%d ", b[c]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text in the question and not as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Change `&b[]` to just `b`.

Comment: 1. You should post your code directly into your question.  Use the "code" icon to format it.  2.  Your image shows a compile error.  You need to fix it before your program can run.

Comment: It compiles and runs if you make @kaylum's change.  If you want it to go all the way down to "1" you need to make `(c > 0)` into `(c >= 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (c > 0)` is the problem. You need to make it 
`if (c >= 0)` to print the value of `1` inside `a[0]`.

Also the first argument at the recursive call of `somefunction` inside `somefunction` needs to omit the `[]`.

As additional hint, to print the value of `11` in `a[6]` you need to change

```
somefunction(a,5);
```

in `main()` to

```
somefunction(a,6);
```

---

The resuming code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void somefunction(const int[], int);

int main() {
  int a[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
  somefunction(a,6);
  return 0;
}

void somefunction(const int b[], int c) {
  if (c >= 0) {
    somefunction(b, c - 1);
    printf("%d ", b[c]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 4 5 7 9 11
```